# Does Acer Aspire P3 suport external usb powered disks

Tags: acer-aspire

(I hope this won't be an inappropriate question for this site as it will be my first question here)

I am thinking in buy an Acer Aspire P3, however is does haven't a SD interface and my doubt is with the help of a sd/USB adapter can I access to SD/SDHC/DSXC cards? Or even better can I access to external usb powered disk?

Does anyone here have experience with this equipment?

Comment: Well, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. Because it has an USB3 connector, it should connect and supply power to any peripheral connected to it. It might drain the battery a little faster if the external disk spends a lot of power, but on most occasions it should work.

Comment: I ask this because, at least, some androids devices even if they have a (micro)USB interface it does not provide power through it

Comment: I was going to suggest that you acquired a SD reader (where I'm at, you can get them at 99c stores or almost) and test whether it powered any sort of thing (most of them have a LED). Then again, wait for more comments.

Comment: @jvverde - Most Android devices are not design to be a USB Host and for good reason. The Acer Aspire P3 is a Windows device, it supports being a USB Host, all Windows devices support being a USB Host. **Any external USB card reader is going to work exactly the same way.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem for that, i know that you can bye USB card readers,

this i the first card reader that i hit on Google: http://www.ebay.in/itm/Amkette-All-in-one-Multi-Format-High-Speed-Card-Reader-USB-2-0-/261266587867?pt=IN_Memory_Cards_Pen_Drives_HDD&hash=item3cd4b3c0db&_uhb=1

but i think that you can find a cheaper one.

I used one at for time ago without any problems, just plugin the USB to the PC.